# Generate a dichotomous variable from a factor

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

I have a dataframe with a factor in it, such as:

```
> var1 <- gl(10, 2, labels=letters[1:10])
> var2 <- c(1:20)
> data <- data.frame(var1=var1,var2=var2)
> data
   var1 var2
1     a    1
2     a    2
3     b    3
4     b    4
5     c    5
6     c    6
7     d    7
...
20    j   20
```

I'm trying to generate a dichotomous variable defined as 1 and 0 for specific values of `var1`. However, when I enter the following code:

```
> data <- data.frame(var1=var1,var2=var2)
> data$var3 <- c(1[which(var1=="a" | var1=="b" | var1=="c" | var1=="d" | 
var1=="e")], 0[which(var1=="f" | var1=="g" | var1=="h" | var1=="i" | var1=="j")])
```

I get the following:

```
> data$var3
 [1]  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

The first item is changed to a 1, but the rest become NAs. How can I obtain the results that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I even understand how you expected your code to function, but it seems like you just want to create a vector of 1 for values from var1 that are either a, b, c, d, or e, and 0 for the rest. If that's the case, then simply use `%in%`, which will create a logical vector, and wrap that in `as.numeric` to convert it to 1s and 0s.

Example:

```
data$var3 <- as.numeric(data$var1 %in% c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
## Or, shorter:
## data$var3 <- as.numeric(data$var1 %in% letters[1:5])
```

---

```
> head(data, 3)
  var1 var2 var3
1    a    1    1
2    a    2    1
3    b    3    1
> tail(data, 3)
   var1 var2 var3
18    i   18    0
19    j   19    0
20    j   20    0
```